# Syntax issue using ON in a MERGE INTO statement

Tags: sql-server, merge

Intellisense error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Location_CVT_Insert, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Stored procedure code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Location_CVT_Insert]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Location_CVT_Insert]
     (@Location_NotificationJson NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO Location_CVT AS C
    USING (SELECT 
               deviceID, lastSeen, locationMapHierarchy, locationCoordinateX, 
               locationCoordinateY, locationCoordinateUnit, geoCoordinateLat,
               geoCoordinateLong, geoCoordinateUnit
           FROM 
               OPENJSON(@Location_NotificationJson)
           WITH 
               (deviceId nchar(17),
                lastSeen varchar(128),
                locationMapHierarchy nvarchar(256),
                locationCoordinateX float,
                locationCoordinateY float,
                locationCoordinateUnit nvarchar(64),
                geoCoordinateLat float,
                geoCoordinateLong float,
                geoCoordinateUnit nvarchar(64)) AS InputJSON) ON (C.deviceId = InputJSON.deviceId)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET C.deviceId = InputJSON.deviceId,
                C.lastSeen = InputJSON.lastSeen,
                C.locationMapHierarchy = InputJSON.locationMapHierarchy,
                C.locationCoordinateX = InputJSON.locationCoordinateX,
                C.locationCoordinateY = InputJSON.locationCoordinateY,
                C.locationCoordinateUnit = InputJSON.locationCoordinateUnit,
                C.geoCoordinateLat = InputJSON.geoCoordinateLat,
                C.geoCoordinateLong = InputJSON.geoCoordinateLong,
                C.geoCoordinateUnit = InputJSON.geoCoordinateUnit

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (deviceId, lastSeen, locationMapHierarchy, 
                locationCoordinateX, locationCoordinateY, 
                locationCoordinateUnit, geoCoordinateLat, 
                geoCoordinateLong, geoCoordinateUnit)
        VALUES (InputJSON.deviceId, InputJSON.lastSeen, InputJSON.locationMapHierarchy, 
                InputJSON.locationCoordinateX, InputJSON.locationCoordinateY, 
                InputJSON.locationCoordinateUnit, InputJSON.geoCoordinateLat, 
                InputJSON.geoCoordinateLong, InputJSON.geoCoordinateUnit);
END
```

It seems that the `ON` statement is the problem. I'd like to select from a JSON object (SQL Server 2016) and if there is a match in my `Location_CVT` table on Device ID, update this entry, else insert a new record.

I am attempting to do something similar to the following example.

```
MERGE INTO Person AS P
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM  OPENJSON(@json)
          WITH (id int, firstName nvarchar(50), lastName nvarchar(50),
                age int, dateOfBirth datetime2) InputJSON
    ON (P.id = InputJSON.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET P.firstName = InputJSON.firstName,
               P.lastName = InputJSON.lastName,
               P.age = InputJSON.age,
               P.dateOfBirth = InputJSON.dateOfBirth
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (firstName, lastName, age, dateOfBirth)
    VALUES (InputJSON.firstName, InputJSON.lastName, InputJSON.age, 
            InputJSON.dateOfBirth);
```

Source: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087995/Inserting-JSON-Text-into-SQL-Server-Table

Comment: Your parenthesis is on the wrong place after the source subquery, it should be something like `...nvarchar(64))) AS InputJSON ON ...` instead of  `...nvarchar(64)) AS InputJSON) ON ...`

Comment: Try removing the `)` after  `AS InputJSON`

Comment: @GarethD When I do that, the InputJSON.<columnname> becomes invalid  for the rest of the query.

Comment: @Xedni, I originally though that as well, but that just creates syntax errors on the rest of the statement keywords below and a majority of the '.', '=' and ','

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, when you have parentheses that span multiple lines, you ensure that your open and close parentheses have consistent indentation, the issue becomes more clear (at least it does to me).

```
MERGE INTO Location_CVT AS C
USING 
(   SELECT 
        deviceID, lastSeen, locationMapHierarchy, locationCoordinateX, 
        locationCoordinateY, locationCoordinateUnit, geoCoordinateLat,
        geoCoordinateLong, geoCoordinateUnit
    FROM 
        OPENJSON(@Location_NotificationJson)
    WITH 
        (   deviceId nchar(17),
            lastSeen varchar(128),
            locationMapHierarchy nvarchar(256),
            locationCoordinateX float,
            locationCoordinateY float,
            locationCoordinateUnit nvarchar(64),
            geoCoordinateLat float,
            geoCoordinateLong float,
            geoCoordinateUnit nvarchar(64)
        ) AS InputJSON
)   ------------------------------------------------- ISSUE IS HERE
    ON (C.deviceId = InputJSON.deviceId)        
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET C.deviceId = InputJSON.deviceId,
            C.lastSeen = InputJSON.lastSeen,
            C.locationMapHierarchy = InputJSON.locationMapHierarchy,
            C.locationCoordinateX = InputJSON.locationCoordinateX,
            C.locationCoordinateY = InputJSON.locationCoordinateY,
            C.locationCoordinateUnit = InputJSON.locationCoordinateUnit,
            C.geoCoordinateLat = InputJSON.geoCoordinateLat,
            C.geoCoordinateLong = InputJSON.geoCoordinateLong,
            C.geoCoordinateUnit = InputJSON.geoCoordinateUnit
```

As you may now be able to see, your subquery that you are using for the source has no alias. It should be:

```
MERGE INTO Location_CVT AS C
USING 
(   SELECT 
        deviceID, lastSeen, locationMapHierarchy, locationCoordinateX, 
        locationCoordinateY, locationCoordinateUnit, geoCoordinateLat,
        geoCoordinateLong, geoCoordinateUnit
    FROM 
        OPENJSON(@Location_NotificationJson)
    WITH 
        (   deviceId nchar(17),
            lastSeen varchar(128),
            locationMapHierarchy nvarchar(256),
            locationCoordinateX float,
            locationCoordinateY float,
            locationCoordinateUnit nvarchar(64),
            geoCoordinateLat float,
            geoCoordinateLong float,
            geoCoordinateUnit nvarchar(64)
        ) AS InputJSON
) AS InputJSON                              -- ALIAS ADDED HERE
    ON (C.deviceId = InputJSON.deviceId)    
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET C.deviceId = InputJSON.deviceId,
            C.lastSeen = InputJSON.lastSeen,
            C.locationMapHierarchy = InputJSON.locationMapHierarchy,
            C.locationCoordinateX = InputJSON.locationCoordinateX,
            C.locationCoordinateY = InputJSON.locationCoordinateY,
            C.locationCoordinateUnit = InputJSON.locationCoordinateUnit,
            C.geoCoordinateLat = InputJSON.geoCoordinateLat,
            C.geoCoordinateLong = InputJSON.geoCoordinateLong,
            C.geoCoordinateUnit = InputJSON.geoCoordinateUnit
```

Comment: That resolves the issue with incorrect syntax near keyword 'ON', but it introduces an issue with the 'InputJSON' alias where the ON condition, SETs and VALUEs are all invalid column names.

Do I need an additional WITH statement before the second alias?

Comment: Moving to original question, too long for comment.

Comment: Do these columns exist in `Location_CVT `? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Yeah they do. I can execute the SP, but when it's run SQL complains that the associated statement is not prepared. I think we've deviated pretty far from my original question, so I'll troubleshoot this some more on my own and perhaps create a new question for that.